# Sharing a pushbutton with multiple boards

Tags: arduino, button, board

I would like to have several identical boards (arduinos) each with its own power supply, and daisy chained with some wiring, each board being able to receive a signal to an input pin when a pushbutton is pressed.

My problem is that I would like to have a single pushbutton that raise the signal on all the boards at once. I understand the ground need to be common between all the boards voltage, but what about the +5V that the button will provide as a signal, can all the boards +5V be connected together as well? And the button would just provide that to all the input pins?

I have no clue how to connect that properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that all boards will be supplied with, for example 9 V, and that each board will have it's own 5V regulator. Then no, you should not connect the 5V supplies because they will not all be exactly 5.00000V There will be one regulator supplying the highest voltage (even of that is 5.01V) and it will take all the load while the other regulators just sit there and do nothing ! (they will think, oh 5.01V is too high, I'll wait untill the voltage goes below 5.005 before I do anything).

But you don't need to connect the 5 V rails together. Since your Arduino's are running on 5 V, anything above 2.5 V is considered a "1". So I would just connect all the inputs of all boards together and connect that to ground with a 10 kohm resistor. Then connect the switch between all those inputs and one of the 5 V supplies on one of the boards. It does not matter which one. To be really safe that no excess current can flow you could place a 1 kohm resistor in series with the switch but this is optional.

Additional note: this assumes all the boards are always powered ON. If one of them is OFF and you press the switch the 5V will provide current through the ESD protection diodes at the input of the microcontroller, raising it's supply. Usually no damage will be done in this situation but if you want a more elegant solution then place a 100 kohm resistor in series with the input of each arduino. That will solve this issue.